# Issues running a game in WINE

Tags: wine, games, steam

Everytime I try to run Sonic Adventure 2 I keep getting a program error and it stops trying to run it in Steam, and in San Andreas everytime I open up the game it works but the screen glitches out to the point where I cannot see anything whatsoever, and when I run it in a virtual desktop I don't see anything at all, it tries to run the game but it just freezes up the desktop for a while, the virtual desktop not the actual Desktop. I know Linux isn't the best for gaming, but is there something I might be able to try? Like Band Aid fix's, I can't dual-boot Windows at the moment, I am not able to buy a product key, so Ubuntu is basically what's keeping my PC from being a paper weight right now (frankly after I get passed the learning curve and the intimidation of the Terminal I kinda prefer Linux) I should have the latest WINE-Staging and I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, anything newer makes this old piece of hardware run really really slow. Both of these games are on Steam.

Answer (score 3):

I highly suggest using Lutris to play Sonic Adventure 2 - Lutris comes with user created scripts to help install programs and often provides better compatibility.

To Install Lutris on Ubuntu 16.04, run the following commands in your terminal:

`echo "deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04/ ./" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris.list`

`wget -q http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04/Release.key -O- | sudo apt-key add -`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install lutris wine`

After installing Lutris, the `lutris` protocol should be working and you should be able to install Sonic Adventure 2 from the install script located here:

https://lutris.net/games/sonic-adventure-2/

As a side note, San Andreas runs perfectly for me with Steam Proton (and even with regular Wine Stable 3.0.2) - perhaps you are having a graphics driver issue.